# ImportError: No module named 'readability'

Tags: python, readability

When I run my .py file I am getting this error I have installed readability and lxml it was working before I don't know why it isn't working right no

```
13:08 ~ $ python3 hiiraanv2.py                                                                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hiiraanv2.py", line 6, in <module>
from readability import Document
ImportError: No module named 'readability'
```

Comment: do you have any other python installed? maybe you have installed these modules to the other python on your system?

Comment: Did you install them with the same user?

Comment: confirm python version. check PYTHONPATH.

Comment: installed on the same user python path version is 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [readability module documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/readability-lxml), shows that class `Document` has to be imported from `readability.readability`.

Usage Example found in the documentation:

```
from readability.readability import Document
import urllib
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
readable_article = Document(html).summary()
readable_title = Document(html).short_title()
```

Comment: I am getting the same error     15:26 ~ $ python3 hiiraanv2.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "hiiraanv2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from readability.readability import Document
    ImportError: No module named 'readability'

Comment: Then, you probably don't have the module properly installed. You either are installing the module in one python version and running the code in another version, or have a screwed PYTHONPATH, or using the wrong virtualenv.

Comment: thanks working now i have uninstalled and installed the readability again